# Set dateValue on TextField type date

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting an error when using the following code :

```
 const {dateBegin,setDateBegin} = React.useState(new Date())
    <TextField
                        id="date"
x                        label="Início "
                        type="date"
                        defaultValue = {"2000-01-01"}
                        multiline={false}
                        onChange={(e) => setDateBegin(e.target.value) }

                        InputLabelProps={{
                            color:'secondary',
                            className:"DatePicker",
                        style : {color:"#ffff",},
                        shrink: true,
                        
                        }}
                        inputProps={{
                            style: { color: "#ffff" },
                          }}
                          
                        />
```

whenever I change the value on the input using the small calendar, the page gives me an error  : TypeError: setDateBegin is not a function. That's weird, I've been using useStates like this since I've started using react.

Comment: `const {dateBegin,setDateBegin}` should be `const [dateBegin,setDateBegin]`

Comment: Oh boy, I hate mondays. Did'n't notice that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re destructuring useState incorrectly. Try:

```
const [dateBegin, setDateBegin] = useState()
```

useState returns this array rather than an object.